# Mapping two disjoint intervals into one interval

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to find a continuous function that maps $[0,1] \cup [2,3]$ onto $[0,1]$. Could someone give me a hint? (Note I haven't taken topology.)

Comment: **Hint:** think it geometrically. You can do translations and expansions/contractions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One such function is: $$f(x)=\begin{cases}x&:\ x\in[0,1]\\ x-2&:\ x\in[2,3]\end{cases}.$$ We can think of this as fixing the $[0,1]$ interval and translating the interval $[2,3]$ to the left by $2$ units.

Answer (score 3):

I think $f(x)=\sin(\pi x)$ works.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x) =\left|x-\frac{3}{2}\right|-\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Thats really neat! How did you think of that?

Comment: The problem has symmetry about $3/2$.  We might as well exploit it.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x) = \frac{1}{2}x(3-x)$. ${}{}{}$

$f_n(x) = \frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{2} \sin ( 2 \pi nx)$, n=1,2,...

Answer (score 1):

$$\min(x,1)=\frac{1+x-|x-1|}{2}$$